# Magento - Checkout - Cart page blank

Tags: magento

I am looking for a solution to my checkout cart page in Magento. When I put items into add to cart then cart page is getting blank.!!

I have tried several options & still it is showing blank. I have enabled cookies etc but still no luck. I am using firefox browser and attached a screen shot of the cookies settings.

Page URL - index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMS4xMTQ6ODEvZXNzZW50aWFsbHkvaW5kZXgucGhwL2NsZWFuc2UuaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/product/2/

Please anyone can help me with this issue??

http://www.itsthe1.com/cookies.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Fundamentals for Debugging a Magento Store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and [PHPs White Screen of Death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 8):

This is a PHP Memory Limit Issues. Its happens to me.
Even if 256 MB will not work so go for 500m

Go to magento Root and .htaccess and change the current value to as per this and then Flush the cache and check your shopping cart and it will work.

```
## adjust memory limit
php_value memory_limit 500M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Please Note: This is not an Extension issues.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I did the above change in .htaccess, but it did not fix the problem. Then I created a php.ini file with the above code and that fixed the problem. Cheers

Comment: In my case, this solution did not fix the problem.  (I set the value in php.ini to 512M)

Comment: this will only solve the problem on apache webservers

Answer (score 1):

This issue does not seem like a cookie problem. You will need to debug the problem more. Open your `index.php` in the web root and add the following lines - `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` & `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` then refresh the page.

This should give you a clear indication of any issues with the php file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply steven. I have tried what you have told above but still no luck. Its still showing blank page. This is my index.php file -> http://www.itsthe1.com/index.zip

Comment: The application was setup in my local PC. Is there any possibilities to check these issue via teamweaver access?? I got stuck with this blank issue like 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added any new modules since its installation? Try disabling all modules that interact with either product page or cart page.

Answer (score 1):

Blank page is a result of error.

Checkout page needs more memory and it has been observed that due to memory constraint there will be out of memory error.Which inturn will result in blank page.

Answer (score 1):

I had gotten the same error. Firstly add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in your index.php to check what is the error.

Mine was `Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory in developer.php line 73`

There was nothing wrong in both of these files. `PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory` is no more autogenerated in magento 2.1.x so to resolve this, add the following in your `vendor/magento/module-vault/etc/di.xml` file in between line 10-15:

```
<preference for="Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterfaceFactory" type="Magento\Vault\Model\AccountPaymentTokenFactory"/>
```

Then flush the cache and check if it still exists. That's how I resolved my error.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with Steven's solution,  When did this problem being to occur,  were there any major changes made?

Comment: This happends when I try to press Add to cart button which means checkout - cart page is getting empty.

Comment: The application was setup in my local PC. Is there any possibilities to check these issue via teamweaver access?? I got stuck with this blank issue like 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is almost always due to a
Memory issue. Try increasing the memory limit, an also enable cache in the admin config.

This usually happens on the cart and checkout if the system doesn't have enough ram
Allocated.

Depending on your setup you can modify this inside the htaccess file or inside php.ini

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have set my memory_limit to 1000M in my php.ini file & enabled cache also but still it gives same problem.

Comment: did you check the htaccess, this will usually have a lower limit than that. do you actually have a decent amount of RAM in the machine?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the php mcrypt module is installed and activated

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check your PHP version.

Comment: If you add an explanation why that might help, this could be accepted as an answer. Ohterwise it should be a comment. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead